# Android app crash reported by Google Play has no stack trace

Tags: android, google-play

I recently noticed that in the Google Play Developer Console that there was a crash reported with an app that I've developed. In the past, I've had a few of these reported so I'm familiar with them. They generally have a nice stack trace that I can use to track down and fix the problem.

The crash that was reported had no stack trace and in fact no suggestion that it had anything at all to do with my app. I'm looking at the data that they've provided and have no idea where to even begin. I've included a screenshot of the problem as reported. Apparently there was a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in libGLES_mali.so - none of these things are meaningful to me.

Any idea what I can do? I am concerned that Google will mark my app as something that is prone to "crashing". What can be done?

[image]

Comment: I encountered similar error before on one of my test devices. After long investigation I figured that device storage is corrupt. In your case I would wait and see if this issue occurs on other devices before I look for solution.

Comment: from the trace it seems like the  android webview crashed.

Comment: Is your app using any native c libraries e.g. unity. libgdx? do you have in your libs folder, directories like: "armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86" ?

Comment: I didn't say, but there have been similar reports on other devices.

Comment: I only need a handful of fairly simple libraries - mainly stuff from Apache. I also use AWS mobile analytics, but that should be okay. This is not a game so no fancy graphics or anything like that.

Comment: do you use native libraries ?! because native exception do not track by main thread

Comment: I do not believe that I'm using any native libraries. Certainly not from my code and I'm not aware of this being done in any of the libraries I use. Is there anything I can do to test whether there are native libraries? Is the fact that there's no real stack trace a good sign that there's something going on natively?